# Use MSTest V1 in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017, mstest

My organization has a large number of legacy test code that is all set up to run on MSTest V1. And until they all have been migrated to MSTest V2, nobody is allowed to MSTest V2.

Now I have run into an unexpected problem. I need to create a new test project, but I can not find a way how to create a new MSTest V1 project in Visual Studio 2017.

In both .NET Core and .NET Framework, it creates a project with MSTest V2. And when I manually try to uninstall the MSTest V2 NuGet Packages and add a reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll it seems that that DLL is actually missing.

Is there a way to get MSTest V1 functionality working like this? Because the existing projects work perfectly fine.

Thank You!

Comment: *"And until they all have been migrated to MSTest V2, nobody is allowed to MSTest V2."* which, realistically, means it's never going to happen. I found that the best way is to gradually transition by writing new tests in a different framework. For optimal results, you should also avoid mixing different frameworks in a single project, recent updates to VS 2017 have broken that workflow.

Comment: I noticed that coded UI test projects do have `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework` referenced. Since unit tests and coded ui tests are a bit related, you could try starting from a coded ui test project.

You also mention that the DLL is missing. Did you check if all components concerning tests (in a broad sense) are installed? You can check this trough the "Microsoft Visual Studio Installer". It's found at "Programs and Features" in Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I am not sure myself why I couldn't find the DLL on the first attempt. When creating another project from scratch, the Quality Tools DLL was snuggly available. Once I picked that one and removed MSTest v2 it worked just fine!